# How to set background color when rotating image using thumbnailator

Tags: java, image

I'm trying to rotate an image using [thumbnailator](https://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/) library. It works fine except I don't see any way to set background color of the new image.

```
Thumbnails.of(image).rotate(45).toByteArray()
```

If I rotate an image 45 degree it makes corners black. If I need to set some other color, how do I do this?

Example of a rotated image with black background:

[image]

Comment: What was the actual `image` object? Is it a `BufferedImage`? Or is it an image file? If so, what is the format of the image? Finally, how did you create the image file that you posted in this question? I'll need those hints to track down what's going on. (I'm the author of the Thumbnailator library)

Comment: The image was BufferedImage. The code which produced the image looks like this: `Thumbnails.of(image).size(100, 60).rotate(45).imageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB).outputQuality(0.8D).outputFormat("jpeg").toByteArray();`

Answer (score 0):

You can transform to an "intermediate" image and then apply your background color.

*This is mostly untested.*

```
Color newBackgroundColor = java.awt.Color.WHITE;

// apply your transformation, save as new BufferedImage
BufferedImage transImage = Thumbnails.of(image)
        .size(100, 60)
        .rotate(45)
        .outputQuality(0.8D)
        .outputFormat("jpeg")
        .asBufferedImage();

// Converts image to plain RGB format
BufferedImage newCompleteImage = new BufferedImage(transImage.getWidth(), transImage.getHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
newCompleteImage.createGraphics().drawImage(transImage, 0, 0, newBackgroundColor, null);

// write the transformed image with the desired background color
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(newCompleteImage, "jpeg", baos);
```